# MongoDB consulta de 2 campos

Tags: json, mongodb

Estoy con una BBDD en mongoDB con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("637367a4c38e976badfe46ad"),
"ID" : 1,
"Name" : "A Dijiang",
"Sex" : "M",
"Age" : 24,
"Height" : 180,
"Weight" : 80,
"Team" : "China",
"NOC" : "CHN",
"Games" : "1992 Summer",
"Year" : 1992,
"Season" : "Summer",
"City" : "Barcelona",
"Sport" : "Basketball",
"Event" : "Basketball Men's Basketball",
"Medal" : null
```

}

Que hace referencia a atletas de los Juegos Olímpicos y su info. Mi pregunta sería cómo puedo acumular las veces que una ciudad (campo "City"), se repite a lo largo de los años (campo "Year").

El resultado que quisiera obtener sería algo como:

```
{
 "Atenas": 3,
 "Londres": 2,
 "Estocolmo": 2,
 "Barcelona: 1,
 ...
}
```

Es decir, con la cantidad de veces que cada ciudad fue sede de los JJOO.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado o investigado? En la [documentación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) podrías encontrar ejemplos muy similares que exponen la solución al problema aquí planteado. ¿Has consultado dicha documentación? Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y [mre]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega todo lo que hayas intentado para resolver el problema, explicando el problema o error. Saludos

Comment: Estoy buscando en la documentación algo similar, pero todavía no encontré exactamente esto, además soy bastante nuevo con mongodb por eso hasta me cuesta entender la documentación

Comment: Empieza por buscar como se hace un `aggregate` y como usar el `$group`

Comment: No encontrarás exactamente tu caso en la documentación. Pero podrías intentar reproducir alguno de los ejemplos y aplicarlo a tu caso concreto. Pista: agrupa por ciudad, y usa `$addToSet` para crear un conjunto de años únicos. Lo demás es pan comido. Saludos